# Is it possible to delay and/or cancel a Show Detail segue for UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I would like to use a `UISplitViewController` to show a list of connectable devices in the master view, and to show information retrieved from a selected device in the detail view.

To do that, when the user taps on a device, I need to attempt to connect to that device. If unsuccessful, there'd be nothing to show and I would display an error message. If successful, I'd read data from the device and display that in the detail view.

The Show Detail segue from the `UISplitViewController` seems to automatically fire immediately after an entry in the master view is tapped. Can I intercept this somehow to add the necessary logic for connection/read? If not, what is an alternative method for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ViewController you can override `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`

```
class Foo: UIViewController {
    func doAsynchStuff(completion: (canProceed:Bool)->()) {
    // ...
    }

    override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if everythingOK {
            return true
        } else {
            // do your stuff
            doAsynchStuff({ (canProceed) -> () in
                if canProceed {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier, sender: sender)
                } else {
                    // present error message
                }
            })
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

If you return `true` the segue will be execute, otherwise you:

1. run your asynchronous code
2. invoke `performSegueWithIdentifier` and when the asynch function has completed you decide what you do looking at the result
3. return `false` to cancel the current segue

Comment: I generally dislike changing state in a `should...` method, but I have to say this is a clever one. I would be inclined to override `performSegue` with this code though...

Comment: @DanielT.: There's nothing wrong in overriding `performSegueWithIdentifier`. And it's the right place where you can stop a segue. From Apple Doc: `Subclasses can override this method and use it to perform segues conditionally based on current conditions. If you do not implement this method, all segues are performed.` - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that there was anything *wrong* with overriding the method per se. I just meant that I prefer to maintain command/query separation when I can, and in this case it can be done. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command–query_separation